# Azure Devops Server (On Prem) add users to organization using rest API

Tags: rest, azure-devops

In Azure devops cloud, I know how to add users into organization using REST API,
The API probably not supported in on-prem servers, and I cannot find how to do it.

Cloud API :

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

The error I get when using on-prem server:

```
  cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND vsaex.azure-devops
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'vsaex.azure-devops'
  }
```

Simpifying, I need this [API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/get-user-entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) to work with Azure devops on-prem server. I can use your help with this.

[Reference Stackoverflow where I found about cloud solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709818/how-to-add-azure-ad-user-to-azure-devops-organisation-programmatically)